# Regex Min 3 of any character Used

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a password validation, and the requirements are that if a character is used, it has to be used 3 times, such as AAABBB, AABBAB, or A999000AA.

I have something to limit the use of each character to 3 times: `^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){3}))*$`

How do I make sure there is a minimum of 3 occurrences for each character?

Comment: Curious... why is this a requirement?

Comment: I wouldn't do this via regex.  Just use javascript, which will make it much easier to understand.  Especially since javascript's regex engine doesn't support lookbehind which will make this a lot more difficult.

Comment: Not sure, my professor is getting creative

Comment: @JPacheco Your question starts with `REGEX` and you accepted an answer that has no regex at all. lol.

Comment: If using regexp is not a requirement, please fix your title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```js
    var password = 'AABBCCBACDDC',
        check = {},
        x;
    for (var i = password.length; i > 0; i--) {
        x = password[i - 1];
        check[x] = check[x] ? (check[x] + 1) : 1;
    }
    for (x in check) {
        if (check[x] != 3) {
            console.log('"' + x + '" occurs ' + check[x] + ' times!');
        }
    }
```

EDIT: simplified, thanks to @torazaburo.

Comment: I'll try it out, what I have right now is: .*(\w).*\1.*\1.* but that's only checking if the first character occurs a minimum of 3 times

Comment: how would I apply that to a specific text box?

Comment: @JPacheco Since your examples show that, for each character, its 3 occurrences may be located anywhere, you can't at all use a regex.

Comment: @JPacheco Assuming your text box is `<input id="my-text-box" ...>`, merely add `var pwd = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;` right before the beginning of my proposed snippet.

Comment: I have the function running but it is not counting the characters, any reason why it wouldn't?

Comment: I would use `pwd in check`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm puzzled: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean instead of `typeof check[pwd] == 'undefined`, which in any case could just be `check[pwd] === undefined`.

Comment: @Unihedron Why have edited my "thanks"? Please explain!

Comment: Your **answer content** is not the area for your **edit summary**. Read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Unihedron Sorry but I keep not understanding. I just carefully read (again) the "How to Answer" article, and didn't find anything which could explain your point of view. And BTW, what do you mean with "edit summary"? Anyway, it's a commonly used kind of courtesy to cite who helped to improve an answer. I must say that I'm pretty hurted by your behaviour, notably downvoting my answer for reasons clearly outside of normal scope. For now, wanting to remain as much objective as possible, I don't revert back again, but please feel obliged to give me a pertinent and understandable explanation. TIA.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like that:

1. Order your string (this reduces complexity)
2. `/^(?:(.)\1{2})+$/` test a regex that matches a *triplet* **one** ore **more** times.

```js
function isStringValid(s) {
  
  return !!s
    .split("")
    .sort()
    .join("")
    .match(/^(?:(.)\1{2})+$/)
  ;
}


/** IGNORE THE REST **/
function ValidateCtrl() {
  var field = document.querySelector('#Test');
  var btn = document.querySelector('#Validate');
  
  function checkValue() {
    
    console.log('val', isStringValid(field.value));
  } 
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', checkValue);
}

document
  .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ValidateCtrl)
;
```

```css
#Test { 
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="Validate">Validate</button>
<input id="Test" />
```

## Update

If you need for **`at least 3`** occurrences of the same character:

- `/^(?:(.)\1{2,})+$/`

finally `\w` matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

- `/^(?:(\w)\1{2,})+$/`